# how to change player icon in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Please i need some one to help me on how to change player icon into my player page in xamarin forms

This is my code:

PlayerPage.xaml

```
                              <StackLayout>
                                           <Button x:Name="btnpause"
                                                    WidthRequest="20" 
                                                    HeightRequest="20"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                    ImageSource="pause.png" />
                                           <Button x:Name="btnPlay"
                                                    WidthRequest="20" 
                                                    HeightRequest="20"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                    ImageSource="play.png" />
                                        <Switch x:Name="switchLoop" IsToggled="False" />
                            </StackLayout>
```

PlayerPage.xaml.cs

```
        ISimpleAudioPlayer player;
        public PlayerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;

            player.Load("music.mp3");


            btnPlay.Clicked += BtnPlayClicked;
            switchLoop.Toggled += SwitchLoopToggled;
        }

        private void SwitchLoopToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current.Loop = switchLoop.IsToggled;
        }

        private void BtnPlayClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current.Play();
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: "how to change player icon" - what does this mean?  Change it to what?  What is the trigger condition?  What have you already tried?  What specific problem are you having?

Comment: For example; if the user wants to play, the pause icon will be display and if the user wants to pause then I player icon will be display too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean like this ,did not added the image .Use a ImageButton instead.

On start the button play and the loop switch , when the switch is True the sounds repeats it self. When start the pause button is showing push it the Play is showing again to resume. The  example project is on Github https://github.com/borisoprit/MusicStackOverflow

```
<StackLayout>
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="btnPlay"
            HeightRequest="50"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Source="Play.png"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="50" />
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="btnPause"
            HeightRequest="50"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Source="pause.png"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="50" 
            IsVisible="false"/>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Text="Loop:"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Switch
            x:Name="switchLoop"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            IsToggled="False"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
```

PlayerPage.xaml.cs i also place the OnAppearing. This is the state of the btnpause Isvisible = false .Music ended the Play button is there and pause is hiding again.

```
 public HeadProjectAudioPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        btnPause.IsVisible = false;

        var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
      
        player.PlaybackEnded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            btnPlay.IsVisible = true;
            btnPause.IsVisible = false;
        };
        player.Load("running.mp3");


        btnPlay.Clicked += BtnPlayClicked;
        btnPause.Clicked += BtnPauseClicked;
        switchLoop.Toggled += SwitchLoopToggled;
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        btnPause.IsVisible = false;
    }

    private void SwitchLoopToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current.Loop = switchLoop.IsToggled;
    }

    private void BtnPlayClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnPause.IsVisible = true;


        btnPlay.IsVisible = false;
        Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current.Play();

       
    }
    private void BtnPauseClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnPlay.IsVisible = true;
        btnPause.IsVisible = false;
        Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current.Pause();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a short example for showing or hiding a button , with the Clicked event. Maybe you can implant it to your own project

Comment: I have implant it to my own project but when its finished playing it couldn't go back to normal play button. when i praise play after finishing playing, the pause button still remain open, instead of showing play button.

Comment: right now the buttons only change in response to click events.  If you also want the buttons to update when the media finishes playing, you will need to add some logic that happens when the media finishes playing

Comment: Ok please endeavor to show me the logic. thank you.

Comment: Look at what events are available in the player.  Or see if there is an `bool` property like Playing that you can bind your controls visibility to

Comment: Please check the above code to assist me. thanks.

Comment: @BasH Please check the above code to assist. I want to you to add some logic into your code that you present to me, because I want the button to update when the media finishes playing. Thank you so much for your contributions to me. I really appreciate.

Comment: I made a small project with image and normal buttons. Show and hide , the loop is also working . Play Pauze and in normal button's Stop. Ajust it to your project . https://github.com/borisoprit/MusicStackOverflow

Comment: Ok Sir, I will do so, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [PlaybackEnded](https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins/blob/025d95e1364b53f35340f29485e0a2f8d9341701/SimpleAudioPlayer/SimpleAudioPlayer/Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.Abstractions/ISimpleAudioPlayer.cs#L14) , it is raised when  audio playback completes successfully  .

You can control the button's visibility  in the event .

##### Code example

```
var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
player.PlaybackEnded += (sender,e)=>
{
     btnPlay.IsVisible = true;
     btnpause.IsVisible = false;
};
```

Comment: it's not yet done

Comment: Did you debug if `PlaybackEnded ` fired when video completed.

Comment: Yes I do so. This is what I need: Please look down @BasH Answered check and assist. I want to you to add some logic into the code in order to update the button when the media finishes playing. Thank you for your contributions. I really appreciate

Comment: Made a change to use PlaybackEnded as @ColeX meant , https://github.com/borisoprit/MusicStackOverflow

Comment: Ok Sir. Thank you.

Comment: Ishaq i updated my answer , if the example helpt you for your project. Please mark it as answer

Comment: Bas H, Of course, really helped me a lot, thank you onece again for your kind concerned. I really appreciated. Thank you.